# generating custom uniqueidentifier sql server

Tags: sql-server, uniqueidentifier

im using sql server 2012, is it possible to generate a uniqueidentifier value based on two or three values mostly varchars or decimal, i mean any data type which takes 0-9 and a-z.

Usually uniqueidentifier varies from system to system. For my requirement, I need a custom one, when ever i call this function, it should get me the same value in all the systems.

I have been thinking of converting the values into varbinary and taking certain parts of it and generating a uniqueidentifier. How good is this approach.

Im still working on this approach.

Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: What's wrong with "select NEWID()"?

Comment: "For my requirement, I need a custom one, when ever i call this function, it should get me the same value in all the systems" Then you don't need a uniqueidentifier ....

Comment: @David Brabant, NEWID() generates random values, but i need the value to be specific to the strings i pass.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, i need the type to be of uniqueidentifier, its for other purpose.

Comment: based on the answers in other forums, i tried this, "SELECT distinct cast(Hashbytes('SHA1',CAST(TableName + ColumnName + ColumnValue AS VARBINARY(max))) as uniqueidentifier) from Locale" can anyone tell me how good is this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is a *hash* of the values. Use [`HASHBYTES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) function to digest your values into a hash. But your definition of the problem contradicts the requirement for  *uniqueness* since, by definition, reducing an input of size M to a hash of size N, where N < M, may generate collisions. If you truly need uniqueness then redefine the requirements in a manner which would at least *allow* for uniqueness. Namely, the requirement for *it should get me the same value in all the systems* must be dropped since the *only* way to guarantee it is to output exactly the input. If you remove this requirement then the new requirement are satisfied by [`NEWID()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) (yes, it does not consider the input, but it doesn't *have* to in order to meet your requirements).

Comment: thank you for mentioning HASHBYTES, it helped a lot. even though there are limitations, i still prefer this approach. I checked this with 113443 records in a table, and I got unique values.

Answer (score 0):

The standards document for Uniqueidentifier goes to some length showing how they are generated. http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt

I would give this a read (especially 4.1.2. as that breaks down how a guid should be generated) and maybe I would keep use the timestamp components but hard code your network location element which will give you what you are looking for.

Comment: it is a very good link, i will go through it once. thank you for sharing.

Comment: this article has a proper way, but is not returning unique values.